# How can I write the Data Generator for the four 7 Segment Displays on my Basys 3 FPGA Board?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, hdl, vivado, hardware

I've been given a task to write the code for a Data Generator and a Symbol converter to run four 7 Segment Displays on a Basys 3 board. This is only my second task in VHDL so I am still learning but I have been able to program a 0 to 9999 Counter which I found challenging. I would really like to be told the best way and given some links or tips on what to do next for it instead of someone just writing the code for me.

The DG has to produce various 4-bit sequences based on the switches you turn on/off and D1 and D2 have to cycle. each 4-bit
data value needs to be represented by two 2-bit"symbols" (e.g. "1011" becomes symbol "10" followed by
the symbol "11";) For each 4-bit value from the DG, an SC entity should output two 2-bit symbols -
which will therefore be running at 2Hz. however, D4 and D3 will remain static.

I have written if statements for the different combinations of switches I will need but I am struggling to wrap my head around how to output the D1 and D2 displays as I know they have to check for a reset and start/stop function as well which has to be the first run through a deBounce function. I have written a deBounce function but I'm not sure how to link it to my reset and start/stop buttons. Below is what I have written so far for the DG entity (i know there is a lot missing and sabout 16 syntax errors but I just outlined briefly what I want to have in the future) :

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Data_Generator is
Port ( i_Clk : in STD_LOGIC;
   i_Reset : in STD_LOGIC;
   i_StartStop : in STD_LOGIC;
   i_CE2Hz : in STD_LOGIC;  
   i_SW : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR );
end Data_Generator;

architecture Behavioral of Data_Generator is
signal i_D4 : integer range 0 to 7;
signal i_D3 : integer range 0 to 15;
signal i_D2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 to 1);
signal i_D1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 to 1);

begin
displayChoice : process (i_Reset, i_StartStop, i_SW)
begin
    if (i_SW = '1000') then
        i_D4 <= 0 ;
        i_D3 <= 1 ;
        if (i_Reset = '1'
        end if;
         
    elsif (i_SW = '0100') then  
        i_D4 <= 1
        i_D3 <= 7
        
    elsif (i_SW = '1100') then
        i_D4 <= 2
        i_D3 <= 14
        
    elsif (i_SW = '0010') then
        i_D4 <= 3
        i_D3 <= 8
           
    elsif (i_SW = '0001') then
        i_D4 <= 6
        i_D3 <= 
        
    elsif (i_SW = '1001') then
        i_D4 <= 7
        i_D3 <= 
        
    else    
        i_D4 <= 0
        i_D3 <= 0
        
    end if;
end process displayChoice;
            
end Behavioral;
```

(what I have for D4 and D3 are what is supposed to be there later on the display)

I would greatly appreciate any help or advice. Please let me know if you would like to see additional code from my other entities or my top level. Thanks

Comment: See the [Basys3 reference manua](https://reference.digilentinc.com/basys3/refmanual)l sections on Basic I/0 where the physical organization is described and Seven Segment Display where the method of anode steering with cathode multiplexing is descirbe. Also see [Introduction to Digital Design  Using Digilent FPGA Boards ─Block Diagram / VHDL Examples](https://reference.digilentinc.com/_media/textbooks:intro_digital_design-digilent-vhdl_online.pdf), Examples 9 and 10. Digilent quite providing VHDL examples after Basys2 which uses the same display and scheme.

Comment: *How can I write...?* is a non-specific question. What isn't clear is what is stopping you.

Comment: hi user1155120, I have read the Basys3 reference manual and it helped with my previous project to create a working 0 to 9999 counter on the 7 Seg Displays but to actually write code I found it minimalistic (which makes sense as it's just a reference manual) however your second link at first glance looks perfect to help me thank you. What is stopping me is my lack of knowledge in linking everything together and writing the code together.

Comment: That PDF is derived from *Digital Design Using Digilent FPGA Boards - VHDL/Active-HDL* Richard E. Haskell, Darrin M. Hanna, 2009 ISBN 978-0-9801337-8-3.